# Convert DOMList array to multidimensional object array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a [DOMNodeList](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) array that i am trying to convert into a multidimensional array. This is my attempt to do that:

```
 $array = (object) array();
            foreach ($this->timeofday as $key => $node) {
                        $array->{$key} = (object) array();

                if (get_class($node) === 'DOMElement') {
                    if ($node->hasAttribute('class')) {
                        if ($node->getAttribute('class') === 'cmil_salong') {
                                $array->{$key}->salong = $node->nodeValue;
                        }

                        if($node->getAttribute('class') === 'cmil_time'){
                                $array->{$key}->time = $node->nodeValue;
                        }

                        if($node->getAttribute('class') === 'mv_3d'){
                                $array->{$key}->threed = $node->nodeValue;
                        }

                        if($node->getAttribute('class') === 'cmil_rs'){
                                $array->{$key}->freeseats = $node->nodeValue;
                        }

                        if($node->getAttribute('class') === 'mv_txt'){
                                $array->{$key}->textad = $node->nodeValue;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (get_class($node) === 'DOMAttr') {
                    if ($node->nodeName === 'href') {
                            $array->{$key}->href = $node->nodeValue;
                    }
                }

            }
```

That produces:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [salong] => Tokyo
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [time] => 15:00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
       (
           [threed] =>
       )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [freeseats] => 20
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [textad] => 
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [href] => http://example.com/1
        ) 
And so on..
```

But the expected result is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [salong] => Tokyo
            [time] => 11:30
            [threed] => 
            [textad] => 1
            [freeseats] => 20
            [href] => http://example.com/1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [salong] ... And so on
        )
```

## **Question**:

1. How can i convert the DOMNodeList to a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

may be this is the thing you want :

```
$mainKey=-1;$keyCount=0;
         $array = (object) array(); $parant = "";
           foreach ($this->timeofday as $key => $node) {
            if(($keyCount == 0) || $keyCount >= 5) {$keyCount = 0;             
                  $mainKey++;$array->{$mainKey} = (object) array();}

            $array->{$mainKey}->{$key} = (object) array();
            if (get_class($node) === 'DOMElement') {
                if ($node->hasAttribute('class')) {
                    if ($node->getAttribute('class') === 'cmil_salong') {
                            $array->{$mainKey}->{$key}->salong = $node->nodeValue;
                    }

                    if($node->getAttribute('class') === 'cmil_time'){
                            $array->{$mainKey}->{$key}->time = $node->nodeValue;
                    }

                    if($node->getAttribute('class') === 'mv_3d'){
                            $array->{$mainKey}->{$key}->threed = $node->nodeValue;
                    }

                    if($node->getAttribute('class') === 'cmil_rs'){
                            $array->{$mainKey}->{$key}->freeseats = $node->nodeValue;
                    }

                    if($node->getAttribute('class') === 'mv_txt'){
                           $array->{$mainKey}->{$key}->textad = $node->nodeValue;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (get_class($node) === 'DOMAttr') {
                if ($node->nodeName === 'href') {
                        $array->{$mainKey}->{$key}->href = $node->nodeValue;
                }
            }

        }
```

There should be parent node checking or if nodes are 5 then count the nodes and change the main array index accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! But this did not solve the issue. This produce an array looking like: `stdClass Object([0] => stdClass Object([0] => stdClass Object([salong] => Tokyo)) and so on..`